# Oracle Cloud stopping due to inactivity

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle Cloud Autonomous Database running in the Free Tier.  Occasionally the database stops. When viewed on the website, the details say that it was stopped due to inactivity.

However, that sometimes happens just a few minutes after reading and writing to the database!

Why is that happening?  Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

There were issues in the algorithm detecting activity on the Always Free Autonomous Databases. Oracle was aware of the issue and the problems should have been fixed by now. None of the instances I monitor have gone down unexpectedly since. Hope it's been the same for you!

Comment: Mine did last week, but you've given me hope! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Read the section "Inactivity Monitoring and Database Stoppage"

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/autonomous-always-free.html#GUID-03F9F3E8-8A98-4792-AB9C-F0BACF02DC3E

Comment: Hello! Link-only answers become not-useful once their link rots. Please add at least a summary of the solution so your answer can stand alone.